# Testing for Linear Independence

Tags: linear-algebra

I am self-studying linear algebra and will greatly appreciate some clarification on this question. There are many like these, and most have to do with trigonometry and I have used similar logic where $cos(x)$ or $sin(x)$ have been set to zero by taking on appropriate $x$ values.

So...we know that a set of vectors is linearly independent when the following condition is met:

$k_1v_1 + k_2v_2 + k_3v_3 + ... + k_nv_n = 0$

given that $k_1 = k_2 = k_3 = ... = k_n = 0$

I was solving one of the question based on this premise and my answer is incorrect. I am hoping that I will be able to clarify my error or gaps in my thinking.

**Question in the book**: **f** = 2 and **g** = $x^2$

**My reasoning**: If $x = 0$ then $0^2 = 0$ then the condition 
$k_1$**f** + $k_2$**g** $= 0$ does not hold as per the requirements of the linear independence definition, which states that the scalars must equal $0$. Here we have a situation where $k_1 = 0$ to make $k_1$**f** $=0$ but $k_2$ can be any real number and the result will be still be zero because **g** $=0$ because $x = 0$. Therefore, we an conclude that the following set of vectors does not satisfy the requirements of linear independence and is linearly dependent.

**Answer to the question by the author**: Using scalars k and c we have

$k$**f** $+ c$**g** $ = k(2) + cx^2 = 0$

Substituting $x=0$ into the equation above gives $2k + c(0)^2 = 2k = 0 \implies k = 0$

Substituting $x=1$ into the equation above gives $2k + c(1)^2 = 2k + c = 0$ because $k = 0 \implies c = 0$. Hence the vectors are linearly independent.

**My Question**: Once we set $x= 0$ does it not mean that at that moment we can set any value for $c$ other than $0$ and still end up with $0$ as a result of the equation because the only way **f** will be $0$ is if $k = 0$? This question has perhaps logically confused me. What could possibly be the reason for setting $x = 1$? When once $x = 0$ scalar $c$ can take on any value other than $0$. Also, **f** $= 2$, which is a constant and the only way to make it $0$ is if $k = 0$. What am I missing?

Comment: You have to show that *both* $k$ and $c$ are zero if the linear combination of the two functions is zero for *all* values of $x$.

Comment: By the way, your phrasing of the definition of linear independence is wrong. The statement "$k_1v_1+k_2v_2+k_3v_3+\cdots+k_nv_n=0$ given that $k_1=k_2=k_3=\cdots=k_n= 0$" is always trivially true regardless of the given vectors. The correct definition is that "$k_1v_1+k_2v_2+k_3v_3+\cdots+k_nv_n=0$ **implies** that $k_1=k_2=k_3=\cdots=k_n= 0$".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The equation $k\cdot 2 + c\cdot x^2 = 0$ holds if and only if there exist such $k$ and $c$ that making the relation correct for any given $x.$ Hence you can plug in any two values of $x$ and solve the equations to find the possible values of $k$ and $c,$ and check that if they are really the right ones.

Hence when you put $x=0,$ any $c$ is suitable, but not for other $c,$ so you can have that conclusion.

Comment: I think you just answered my question...I was being short sighted I guess...I saw that it works for one number then it must for all. So basically I should consider for all instead of there exists.

Comment: Right! When I just tasted pure math sometimes I was also confused by the logic system. Discussion will make us better~

Answer (score 0):

$k\cdot 2 + c\cdot x^2$ is a polynomial of degree at most $2$ in $x\,$, therefore it can have at most two roots unless it is identically $0\,$. For the equality $k\cdot 2 + c\cdot x^2 = 0$ to hold for $\forall x\,$, the polynomial must have infinitely many roots, which can only happen if it is the identically $0$ polynomial i.e. $k=c=0\,$.